# React Native prevent modal closing on overlay click

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a Modal with a custom height which doesn't take up the entire screen. I would like to prevent the Modal from closing when the user clicks on the overlay or outside the Modal Container. Below is a screen shot of how the modal displays

[image: Modal Display in app]

I have wrapped the Modal Component around `TouchableWithoutFeedback` and setting the Modal transparent to `false` but it still closes when the user taps outside the Modal.

Below is my current configurations of the Modal.

```
 onShow = () => {
        // performs slide in animation
        this.animation();
    };
      
return (

  <Modal transparent visible={visible} onShow={this.onShow}>
                <View
                    style={styles.flex}
                    onLayout={event => {
                        let {height: heightFull} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
                        this.setState({
                            height: getHeightView(heightFull, ratioHeight),
                        });
                    }}>
                   {* Modal Body * }
                    <Animated.View>
                    {* Some other content *}
                    </Animated.View>
                    {* End of Modal Body *}

                </View>
            </Modal>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the react-native-modal package, with it's style set to margin: 0 and justifyContent: "flex-end". Within this, I maintain a View with flex:1 and justifyContent: "flex-end". Then create the modal container (the white section) and wrap the children within TouchableWithoutFeedback inside this container.

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    modalWrapper: {
      margin: 0,
      justifyContent: "flex-end",
  },
    modalContainer: {
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    borderRadius: 30,
  },
   contentSection: {
    marginTop: 32,
    marginHorizontal: 40,
  },
})

export default function YourComponent(){
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>your map content here</Text>
      </View>
      <ReactNativeModal style={styles.modalWrapper}>
         <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
          <ModalHeaderSection title="Available pay" />
          <View style={styles.contentSection}>
            <Text>
              Modal content
            </Text>
        </View>
      </ReactNativeModal>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).